# wp salient theme social media based on language

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wpml

I am using the salient theme and it seems that it doesn't support differents social media based on the current language.

In order to solve this I modified wp-content/themes/salient/nectar/redux-framework/options-config.php to add this functionality.

i'm detecting the language with

```
   $my_current_lang = apply_filters( 'wpml_current_language', NULL );
```

And changed the config array for facebook like this:

```
// for the checkbox
array( 
            'id' => 'use-facebook-icon-'.$my_current_lang,
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'title' => __('Use Facebook Icon', NECTAR_THEME_NAME), 
            'subtitle' => '',
            'desc' => ''
        )
//for the url input field
array(
            'id' => 'facebook-url-'.$my_current_lang, 
            'type' => 'text', 
            'title' => __('Facebook URL', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
            'subtitle' => __('Please enter in your Facebook URL.', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
            'desc' => ''
        ),
```

Independently is working as expected, the problem that I've encountered is that whenever I set the social media for "en" it overwrites the configuration for "fr" with empty values and vice-versa.

So I guess that I have to find a way to disable the overwriting.

Is there another wa to achieve this? Doing this with wpml was the first option that look into but couldnt find a way to have different values for the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your modifications in the footer.php file around line 147 depending on your version.  Otherwise your changes will be overwritten when you update the core theme.  You can add some logic to this line which I cut and paste from it.  I can't test this because I don't have WPML but you get the idea from this example.

Your issue is that you shouldn't be making changes to core theme files, you need to come up with a different solution that is future proof.  I don't know the salient theme, there may be hooks provided to add in custom options.  Failing this, you can add custom options to WordPress and do it that way.  Then just make changes to the footer.php file to display the social icons.

```
<?php
$my_current_lang = apply_filters( 'wpml_current_language', NULL );

if( $my_current_lang == 'en' ) {
    if(!empty($options['use-facebook-icon']) && $options['use-facebook-icon'] == 1) { ?> 
        <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $options['facebook-url']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> </a></li> 
    <?php 
    }
} 
elseif( $my_current_lang == 'fr' ) {
    // Enter custom code here
}
?>
```

Comment: I have done this in the footer but it thought it wasnt relevant so i didnt add it in my question. the problem is that I cant add 2 diferent urls for i.e. facebook in the control panel. I guess that i could hardcode the social media urls but imo is not the best option

Comment: It is relevant.  You can add your own custom fields in WordPress General Settings and reference those in your footer template.

Comment: Can i add my own custom fields and will be managable from the theme control panel?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to manage the social media links for all languages with the theme control panel, So far my issue is that the theme overrides the configuration for all the none active languages.

Comment: I've updated my answer, don't update the core theme files this solution is not future proof.